# Providing solutions from my blog

Tags: discussion, answers, site-policies

Can I answer a question by providing link to my own blog, if it answers the question properly? Is it wrong? Will I be violating any rules of this forum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is totally fine to add links to your blog in your posts.

But, your answers should by them self answer the question. You should not have to click on the link to grasp what you proposes, and how to implement the solutions suggested.

The link should only be supplied as a reference, and to provide really detailed instructions or similar.

Your answer should still be as helpful as possible, even if the link breaks.

Here is a quote from the help section regarding this:

> Provide context for links
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Source: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer